# difference between c's expression and c++'s expression

Tags: c++, c, operator-precedence

```
int main()
{
   int i=3;
   (++i)++;        
   printf("%d",i);
}
```

This programs works with g++ compiler but not gcc.
If i write i++++ or ++i++ it doesn't work in cpp also.
I think there is difference between c-expression and c++-expression.
Can somebody explain about L-value and R-value ?

Comment: accidently i pressed rollback button !

Comment: Silly expressions like this are not valid (and not parse-able by humans) so trying to work out why one language accepts them while the other does not is mute.

Comment: "works" only makes sense if you can explain what you thought it would do. What did you think `(i++)++` should actually do?

Comment: @Martin York: It seems ++++i is a silly expressions.Yes it is difficult parse(by humans).But still these are valid according to precedence and associativity rules and hold meaning....

Comment: They don't hold meaning because the outer operation needs an lvalue to modify. If the result of ++ was an lvalue, then you likely also have a sequence point problem that creates undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jagan: Please don't change the code example after the question as been answered (especially as you've accepted an answer). It makes the accepted answer incorrect.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: It'll not repeat again.

Comment: @RBerteig:Could you please provide an example where sequence point creates undefined behavior.

Comment: @ Jagan: It is not valid according to the semantics of the language and thus is silly. Anything that is this hard read will not be used in real code. The rest of your team will come and tell you to stop being stupid and fix the code. You will NEVER (EVER) see any of these syntactically silly looking constructs in real code. Anything hard to read is hard to maintain. The whole part of having a high level language that is flexible is to make the code EASY to maintain so don't deliberately try and abuse this trust.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit: This answer is incorrect for the updated question, it applies to the question as originally stated.**

`(i++)++` shouldn't work with either gcc or g++, whether or not they are parsing the file as C or C++ in both languages postfix increment requires an *lvalue* as an operand and the result is an *rvalue*.

(Note that *rvalue* is only used formally in C++. In C the results of expressions are either explicitly *lvalues* or they're just not *lvalues*. The term *rvalue* isn't used in the normative text of the C standard at all.)

Simplisticly, an *lvalue* is an expression that refers to an object, i.e. conceptually a region of storage somewhere. A modifiable *lvalue* is something that it is valid to assign to so can appear on the *left* hand side of an assignment expression.

An *rvalue* is just a value, something that you can assign a modifiable *lvalue* from, but not something that you can assign to. It can only appear on the *right* side of an assignment expression.

`g++` gives me the error: `lvalue required as increment operand`.

Prefix increment (and decrement) are slightly different. In C++ the result of a prefix increment is explicitly an *lvalue* (5.3.2/1 [expr.pre.incr]); in C it is explicitly not an *lvalue* (6.5.3.1 states that ++E is equivalent to (E+=1); 6.5.16 says that the result of any assignment is not an lvalue).

`(++i)++` is, therefore, semantically correct only in C++, however it has *undefined behaviour* because you are storing a value to an object twice without an intervening *sequence point*.

Comment: @Charles Bailey:My guess is c-expression returns r-value and c++-expression returns l-value.

Comment: @Jagan: Why do you think you should guess? It's just not true; in both C and C++ the result of postfix increment expression is an _rvalue_.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: What about preincrement expression ?

Comment: @Jagan: The result of a prefix increment is an lvalue in C++ only, but your question doesn't (or didn't until your edit) mention prefix increment operators.

Comment: For user-defined types in C++, rvalues *can* appear on the left-hand side of an assignment, for example `std::string("hello") = std::string("world")`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Yes, there are discrepancies in C++ between the traditional use of _rvalue_ and what's actually true. In your example `op=` resolves to a member function call and you can call functions on rvalues of class type.

Answer (score 0):

From wiki:

> Some languages use the idea of lvalues
>   and rvalues. Lvalues are values that
>   have  addresses being programmatically
>   accessible to the running program
>   (e.g., via  some address-of–operator
>   like "&" in C++), meaning that they
>   are variables or  dereferenced
>   references to a certain memory
>   location. Rvalues can be lvalues  (see
>   below.) or non-lvalues—a term only
>   used to distinguish from lvalues. In
>   C,  the term lvalue originally meant
>   something that could be assigned to
>   (coming  from left-value, indicating
>   it was on the left side of the
>   assignment  operator), but since
>   'const' was added to the language,
>   this now is termed a  'modifiable
>   lvalue'.

Answer (score 0):

$5.2.6-

The value obtained by applying a postfix ++ is the value that the operand had before applying the operator. [Note: the value obtained is a copy of the original value ] The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type or a pointer to a complete object type. After the result is noted, the value of the object is modified by adding 1 to it, unless the object is of type bool, in which case
it is set to true. [Note: this use is deprecated, see annex D. ] **The result is an rvalue.** The type of the result is the cv-unqualified version of the type of the operand. See also 5.7 and 5.17.

$5.3.2/1-

"The operand of prefix ++ is modified by adding 1, or set to true if it is bool (this use is deprecated). **The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue.**"

That should explain the error you are getting for C++.